# Google Plus public search activities with keyword using R

Tags: r, search, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to fetch data from the Google Plus API but I only know how to search if I know the `user_id`.

Here's how I get the JSON using `RCurl` library:

```
data <- getURL(paste0("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/",
 user_id,"/activities/public?maxResults=100&key=", api_key),
 ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

I have tried formatting the URL like the documentation on [google](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/search)
like so:

```
data <- getURL(paste0("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/",
    keyword,"?key=",api_key),ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it even possible to search using a keyword from R or not? As R isn't in the supported programming languages for the API according to this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/)

Comment: Can you please share what type of error messages you get?

Comment: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work.
The `GET` request should be formatted as:

```
data <- getURL(paste0("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?key=",api_key,"&query=",search_string),ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```